# Multiple Joomla websites with in One installation and database

Tags: php, drupal, joomla

Is it possible(out of the box) to have multiple website running on one Joomla installation.

The idea is to give clients a unique domain(or sub domain) and based on the request coming from a particular domain the view should be assembled (theme selection, articles, pages)..
Is it possible.. ??

It important that for each domain we should have a unique theme.

I am not particular about Joomla..If the same is possible with ease in any other CMS like Drupal,etc then please share your thoughts about the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal this is called "multisites" and it's easy to have each site have its own theme and/or even have additional modules used only on some sites, but all sites generally using the same Drupal installation. Anyway, what you describe is commonly done in Drupal and not too hard to accomplish.

More info here: http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about installation, but you can store all the data into a single database, but keep in mind that it is possible with multiple prefixes,

means like you have two joomla sites one with 'jos_' prefix(by default joomla prefix, you can change this) and the other with different prefix